# Extracting content of HTML tag with specific attribute

Tags: html, node.js, regex

Using regular expressions, I need to extract a multiline content of a tag, which has specific id value. How can I do this?

This is what I currently have:

```
<div(.|\n)*?id="${value}"(.|\n)*?>(.|\n)*?<\/div>
```

The problem with this is this sample:

```
<div id="1">test</div><div id="2">test</div>
```

If I want to replace `id="2"` using this regexp (with `${value} = 2`), the whole string would get matched. This is because from the tag opening to closing I match everything until id is found, which is wrong.

How can I do this?

Comment: See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). And `(.|\n)*?` is something that is most likely to cause a huge slowdown.

Comment: What's `${value}` suppose to be?

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression for this, instead of using functions like `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: Becuase it's not exacly a correct HTML, but instead some internal templating engine, which I can't parse with a HTML parser.

Comment: `${value}` is any numeric value, which I want to find as ID attribute

Comment: A simple way though is to do `<div\s[^>]*?id="2"[^>]*?>([\S\s]*?)</div>`

Comment: Use a DOM parser... don't use regex for this task.  A DOM parser *can* handle your invalid HTML in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple way is to use

Raw:  `<div(?=\s)[^>]*?\sid="2"[^>]*?>([\S\s]*?)</div>`

Delimited: `/<div(?=\s)[^>]*?\sid="2"[^>]*?>([\S\s]*?)<\/div>/`

Use the variable in place of `2`.

The content will be in group 1.

Comment: Added a delimited version

Answer (score 0):

Change `(.|\n)` to `[^>]` so it won't match the `>` that ends the tag. Then it can't match across different divs.

```
<div\b[^>]*\bid="${value}"[^>]*>.*?<\/div>
```

Also, instead of using `(.|\n)*` to match across multiple lines, use the `s` modifier to the regexp. This makes `.` match any character, including newlines.

However, using regular expressions to parse HTML is not very robust. You should use a DOM parser.

Comment: I can't, "Becuase it's not exacly a correct HTML, but instead some internal templating engine, which I can't parse with a HTML parser." ;)